# Error for inline assembly in android studio 3

Tags: android, java-native-interface

I am using android studio 3 and ndk 17.0.4754217. So I want to execute this function.

```
void* thread_one(void* arg){
   LOGD("Thread 1");
   __asm__ __volatile__("sub r0, r0, r1");
}
```

But when I compiled it, it gave me this error.

```
error: unknown use of instruction mnemonic without a size suffix
__asm__ __volatile__("sub r0, r0, r1");
                     ^
<inline asm>:1:2: note: instantiated into assembly here
    sub r0, r0, r1
    ^
    1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

I don't know how to fix it. I tried "subs" but still failed. Can anyone give me some suggestions about how to solve this problem?

/* things I changed */

In the build.gradle(Module:app), I added

```
arguments '-DANDROID_TOOLCHAIN=clang','-DANDROID_ARM_MODE=arm'
```

to android.defaultConfig.externalNativeBuild.cmake so it will work as arm mode instead of thumb. However, it won't help.

I added

```
abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86'
```

to android.defaultConfig.ndk. Again, it won't help.

I also tried thumb mode and change the 'sub' to 'subw' which doesn't help.

Comment: `abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a','x86'` That assembly code won't compile for x86. You'll either have to remove x86 from the ABIs you build for, or find some way to conditionally compile that piece of code only when building for ARM.

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I created an arm image and now everything works well.